# How to detect if script is being called directly or via node with yargs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I am writing a CLI utility in NodeJS using [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

Yargs has an `.usage()` function that I use as follows:

```
yargs.usage("\nUsage: node $0 --input=path/to/input/file --output=path/to/output/file")
```

When I run `node cli.js --help`, it displays the following, as expected:

```
Usage: node cli.js --input=path/to/input/file --output=path/to/output/file
```

Clearly yargs is expanding the `$0` placeholder to `cli.js`, which is great. This is why I manually included `node` in the `.usage()` call.

But this way, when I finally publish my utility as a CLI tool, if someone install it using `npm install -g`, I'm afraid the usage display will be

```
Usage: node my-utility --input=path/to/input/file --output=path/to/output/file
```

While obviously I'd like it to be

```
Usage: my-utility --input=path/to/input/file --output=path/to/output/file
```

How can I make this conditional check so that I only print `node` in the usage when it was really called this way (as opposed to being called directly)?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv0

Comment: @Bergi - That didn't work. It yields "node" for both "node my-cli.js" and "my-cli" (after npm link).